# Why am I unable to add my flutter iOS app to my firebase project?

Tags: flutter, firebase

I want to add my flutter IOS app into my firebase project. After running these commands consecutively,

```
flutter clean 
flutter packages upgrade
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli 
flutterfire configure --project=firebase_project_name
```

I keep getting the following error in my `firebase-debug.log`:

```
[info] Create your IOS app in project project_name:
[debug] [2023-01-03T09:49:49.951Z] >>> [apiv2][query] POST https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/project_name/iosApps [none]
[debug] [2023-01-03T09:49:49.952Z] >>> [apiv2][body] POST https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/project_name/iosApps {"displayName":"electric_viewing_ios (ios)","bundleId":"com.elec_view.electric_viewing_ios"}
[debug] [2023-01-03T09:49:50.566Z] <<< [apiv2][status] POST https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/project_name/iosApps 400
[debug] [2023-01-03T09:49:50.567Z] <<< [apiv2][body] POST https://firebase.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/project_name/iosApps {"error":{"code":400,"message":"Request contains an invalid argument.","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT"}}
[debug] [2023-01-03T09:49:50.569Z] HTTP Error: 400, Request contains an invalid argument.
[debug] [2023-01-03T09:49:50.894Z] FirebaseError: HTTP Error: 400, Request contains an invalid argument.
    at responseToError (C:\Users\ipasn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\responseToError.js:49:12)
    at RetryOperation._fn (C:\Users\ipasn\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\apiv2.js:288:77)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
[error]
```

---

Where am I going wrong? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some places where there the default bundle id still exist.

By default "CFBundleIdentifier" support to be the `${PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER}`. I think you changed it directly in the **Info.plist**.

Just try to revert these changes & search for `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` in the vscode project. You will see there are few pages (or one depanding on your project target platforms) where this key is still mapping to the old bundle id. Change the bundle ids in these places to your required bundle id.
Mainly for mobile you have to make changes in `project.pbxproj`.

Then retry `flutter clean` & `flutterfire configure` command again.

Comment: I tried everything that you said, now I am unable to add my app to firebase. Please check my post.

Comment: Bundle id don't support '_' underscore. Remove that and try again.

Answer (score 1):

After much surfing, I found out that `firebase` doesn't allow underscores( **_** ) in `bundle ID`, removing that and then reconfiguring again solved the issue.

Comment: I see you already got the solution for that problem. Great!!

Comment: This saved my day. Still relevant a year later